# Modify two ImageButton's visibility when mouse hover an image on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table which contains an Image and two ImageButtons over it, what I want to achieve is that this ImageButtons come visible only when the mouse is over the Image I mentioned before

I've tried some solutions but they seem to work only on WinForms.

Edit:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using AjaxControlToolkit;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

  namespace Slider.Web
  {
   public partial class Slider_Web : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton1.Visible = false;
        ImageButton2.Visible = false;
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    public static AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides()
    {
        return new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] { 
            new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("bytes.aspx?FileName=grua.jpg", "title", "tecnologia", "http://www.qwe.com"),
            new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("bytes.aspx?FileName=aluminio.jpg", "title", "tecnologia", "http://www.qwe.com"),
        };
    }

    private void Image1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ImageButton1.Visible = true;
        this.ImageButton2.Visible = true;
    }

    private void Image1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ImageButton1.Visible = false;
        this.ImageButton2.Visible = false;
    }
}
}
```

That just make the ImageButtons invisible but I can't make them visible when the mouse is over the Image.

Edit:

```
            <table style="width:980px; background-color: #e2f1f8; position: relative; left: 7px;">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">

                    <div aria-level="0" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                        <div aria-level="1" style="position: absolute; z-index: inherit; left: 0px; top: 125px;">
                            <asp:ImageButton CssClass="imb" ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="100px" ImageUrl="bytes.aspx?FileName=flecha_izq.png" Width="120px" BackColor="Transparent" ImageAlign="Right" style="margin-right: 0px" />
                        </div>


                    <asp:Image CssClass="img" ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="350px" Width="980px" ImageAlign="Middle" BackColor="#E2F1F8" />
                    <asp:SlideShowExtender ID="Image1_SlideShowExtender" runat="server" AutoPlay="True" Enabled="True" ImageDescriptionLabelID="Label1" Loop="True" NextButtonID="ImageButton2" PlayInterval="4000" PreviousButtonID="ImageButton1" SlideShowServiceMethod="GetSlides" SlideShowServicePath="" TargetControlID="Image1" UseContextKey="True"></asp:SlideShowExtender>
                        <div aria-level="1" style="position: absolute; z-index: inherit; right: 0px; top: 125px;">
                            <asp:ImageButton CssClass="imb" ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="bytes.aspx?FileName=flecha_derecha.png" Width="120px" BackColor="Transparent" Height="100px" ImageAlign="Left" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Names="Arial Rounded MT Bold"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Those are my ASP tags, the CSS code is on my HTML code's HEAD as

```
    <style type="text/css" >
.imb {
     visibility: hidden
}

 .img:hover ~ input[type="image"] {
     visibility:visible
}
```

Comment: Hook into the [`onmouseover` event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp). Have you tried anything? Being new doesn't excuse you from asking crappy questions. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show us your code please. If you have none write some first.

Comment: @tnw I've already tried some stuff, that event doesn't seem to have what I need, if it's that easy why don't you try to help instead of saying things which doesn't help anyone, nobody has answer my question so it may be harder of what you think, or maybe no one wants to answer or I'm not giving enough details, but considering this is a community forum and no one else has commented, i'll take my first option.

Comment: @Sharpr Just trying to get you to add detail to your question. What makes you think `onmouseover` is not what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this in server-side code. In fact don't do it in code at all, this could be done purely in CSS styles.

Let's say your buttons (and image you need to hover over) are defined like this

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="img0.gif"/>

<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="img1.gif" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="img2.gif" />
```

Add a CSS Classes to their markup like this

```
<asp:Image CssClass="img" ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="img0.gif"/>

<asp:ImageButton CssClass="imb" ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="img1.gif" />
<asp:ImageButton CssClass="imb" ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="img2.gif" />
```

And define the the classes as

```
<style type="text/css" >
   .imb {
         visibility: hidden
    }

     .img:hover ~ input[type="image"] {
         visibility:visible
    }
</style>
```

(you can place this definition in a separate stylesheet or in page HEAD)

That's it. Initially image buttons are hidden via "imb" class. But when you hover over image the selector makes *all sibling* of `input type="image"` visible.

Comment: I've just tried this out but it didn't work, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I set Image1 CssClass to img, and ImageButton1 and ImageButton2 to imb, I've wrote in the page <Head> the content on the <style> tags just as you wrote it but it doesn't show the ImageButtons, they remain invisible.

Comment: Please update your question by posting ASPX markup of the buttons and the image

Comment: Can you place image above both image buttons or does it have to be in between?

Comment: Not so fast :) I just asked if you could do this change in your design. If you can then use this updated class for "img:hover": `.img:hover ~ div > input[type="image"] {
         visibility:visible
    }` Since your buttons are inside of DIVs, a slight adjustment is needed

Comment: Still doesn't works, anyways I've found a solution by hidding the divs which contains the ImageButtons and changing some of the code, thanks for the idea man.

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful :) That's the best of both worlds, you get some initial thought and then develop it into your own code. Good work!